# Was there a Wilhelm Scream in Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, wilhelm-scream

I understand that it is difficult to prove a negative, but I did not notice a ["Wilhelm Scream"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_scream) in Rogue One. I remember it in (I believe) all three of the original trilogy and it felt somewhat amiss not to have one.

**Did I just miss it?**

Comment: I thought I heard it when some imperial dropped from the platform during the rebel attack on Eadu.

Comment: I think that's where I most expected one, and didn't get it, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 11):

**There is a 'Wilhelm Scream' found at the start of the Rebel Attack on Jedha.**

A grenade is thrown in front of the armoured transport, followed by a number of Stormtroopers being shot (timestamp 00:31:20). During that initial gunfight you can hear the *start* of the classic 'Wilhelm Scream' but cut short by gunfire.

You can hear the end of the scream about two seconds later.