# Was there a Wilhelm Scream in The Last Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

The famous "[*Wilhelm Scream*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wilhelm_scream)" sound effect has been found in every canon Star Wars film, most recently in [The Force Awakens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7eCGbt1XTU) and [Rogue One](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/148384/was-there-a-wilhelm-scream-in-rogue-one)

**Was it used in The Last Jedi?**

Comment: Related: [Was the famous “Wilhelm Scream” used in “The Last Jedi?”](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83789/49)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Building on Praxis' excellent answer, we can hear the scream distinctly at [timecode 2:15:30](https://youtu.be/Dc0v2bcOJ3g?t=12) as Kylo Ren backswings his sword at Luke.

[image]

Comment: You've finished this off nicely.  I do think you should accept yours, when the time comes. :-)

Comment: Interesting. Now the question is *why* is it in that scene?

Comment: @RedCaio - Because it's traditional, but at the same time the director probably didn't want it. This will be the compromise.

Comment: @Valorum : It's probably hidden there to give fans a bit of a challenge.  Finding these screams has become sport. :-)

Comment: Links are dead now

Comment: In the version on disney plus the scream is a bit earlier at more like 2:15:20

Answer (score 17):

## My ears heard one...

...near the end of the film.  Having seen the film twice now, **I believe I heard it during the fight between Kylo and Luke (or rather Luke's projection) in front of the mine doors, when Luke ducks out of the way of Kylo's first strike.**

This article concurs with my hearing:

[GamesRadar: *The Last Jedi* Easter Eggs](http://www.gamesradar.com/star-wars-the-last-jedi-easter-eggs/)